# How to extract only numerics from string in PostgreSQL 8.0.2 Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, regexp-substr

I only want the numeric part of this string column:

| identity |
| --- |
| student:1234 |
| student:56 |
| student:789 |
| id:driver_license-111-AZ |
| id:learner_permit-222-NY |

So that the output should be:

| wanted |
| --- |
| 1234 |
| 56 |
| 789 |
| 111 |
| 222 |

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2 (Amazon Redshift) and I think `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(identity,'[0-9]') FROM table` should work. But it does not. I tried multiple variations of optional arguments in the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) but I can't get it to work. Would someone please help me? With this function or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` should work assuming you use the correct regex pattern:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(identity, '[0-9]+')  -- [0-9]+ means one or MORE digits
FROM yourTable;
```

You might also be able to phrase this using a regex replacement:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(identity, '[^0-9]+', '')  -- strip non digit characters
FROM yourTable;
```